# Is there a simple way to know the gender of a person proper noun in NLTK or spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, spacy

I need to know if the a person proper noun reffers to a boy or to a girl using spacy or nltk. I tried the wordnet dictionary but I ws not able to find this information.

Example:

Alexander => Male

Sophie => Female

Comment: What about Dana? There are two men on my street named that and one woman. And we all hang out together sometimes. Forget about computers, even people get confused.

Comment: Yes. I know. But Dana is an exception.

Comment: You can disambiguate Dana using the context around the name. In the end of the day, these are all statistical models. Probability is king.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way for spaCy or NLTK to tell the gender of a `PERSON` entity.

There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Use spaCy PhraseMatcher and feed in male and female name. This would be equivalent of a dictionary lookup.
2. Train a custom spaCy model and teach it what male and female names are (it would still be ideal to start with 1, use it to detect male and female names in your examples texts, use the indices of the start and end of the match to detect to label your example texts and then use that to train a generalized model).